# Lines appear segmented after enabling depth testing

Tags: opengl

If I draw a series of line segments in OpenGL, where each line segment is small, the resulting line looks smooth and without breaks. But if I enable depth testing with

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

then the line appears as disconnected segments, and not smooth. My application requires depth testing to be on. Is there a way that smooth line drawing can be preserved with depth testing?

Comment: That doesn't sound expected. Are you clearing the depth buffer?

Comment: Well, if "smooth lines" refers to enabling  `GL_LINE_SMOOTH`, I wouldn't be surprised at all. That's a feature which should never have been introduced at all (together with `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH`, of course), because it is just conceptually broken beyond repair.

Comment: Some additional code would be useful, but it sounds like you might be drawing multiple line segments in the same location. This isn't a problem if depth testing is disabled, but z-fighting will cause something similar to what you describe with the test enabled. Check to make sure your rendering loop doesn't render multiple lines in the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments it may be an expected behaviour if you use GL_LINE_SMOOTH. As a result of using it lines are trying to draw pixels beyond the actual "line". If your lines are overlapping in that place you will get a segmented line because Z-order of drawing is not respected.

One simple solution that comes to my mind is to first draw the whole scene with depth-test and depth-writes. Then for drawing your lines keep the depth test on but disable writing to depth buffer. This way you will only test your lines against the scene not against each other and you can keep the "smooth" look that you get without depth testing.

Comment: That did the trick. Although I first had to draw the lines first with glDepthMask(FALSE), then the rest of the scene with glDepthMask(TRUE). Drawing the other way around (scene first then lines) produced strange white artifacts.